# Is it valid to substitute $x$ for $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ when taking a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I am trying to find $$f'(x)$$ with $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\arctan(x)}$$
would this be the same as finding the derivative of $$\frac
{x}{\arctan(x)}$$ or can I not make this substitution because of the different domains of $x$ and $\sin(\arcsin(x))$

Comment: Note your title has the order of the functions reveresed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different functions in your title and body. For $\sin(\arcsin(x)) $ the answer is yes, but the domain is restricted to $[-1,1]$. For $\arcsin(\sin(x)) $ the answer is a resounding no, but it's true if you restrict to $[-\pi/2, \pi/2] $. The domain is larger than this, however, so on the whole domain the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only for $x$ satisfying $$-1\le x\le 1.$$ Otherwise, the equality $$x=\sin\arcsin x$$ is manifestly false.

Comment: so if the domain is no restricted in the question I can't make this substitution?

Comment: @J.g No you cannot. Indeed, as Peter Foreman hints at above, the function $x\mapsto \arcsin x$ is defined only for $|x|\le 1.$

Comment: The implicit domain of the original function (assuming real variables) is $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$. This is a valid substitution. The resulting expression will be limited to the same domain.

Comment: The domain *is* restricted to $[-1, 1]\setminus \{0\}$ and can't not be.  The function isn't defined for any other values.

Comment: @MPW The resulting function $$x/\arctan x$$ is defined for almost all real numbers whereas the original is defined only for almost all real numbers absolutely less than unity. So, one need beware of the restrictions on $x$ for which the substitution is valid.

Comment: @fleablood Please see my reply to MPW above. It's for you too, but I couldn't tag two in the same comment.

Comment: @Allawonder : Maybe we’re saying the same thing? It’s absolutely true that for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ one has $f(x) = x/\arctan x$. I understand that the “natural” domain of $h(x) = x/\arctan x$ is larger than the natural domain of $f$.

Comment: The question was "if the domain is no restricted in the question I can't make this substitution?" I maintain the answer is the the domain *is* restricted and can not not be restricted.  So the substitution of $\sin(\arcsin x)$ for $x$ can *always* be made.  Had the question been either "Can we make the substitution and not restrict the domain *after* the substitution is made" or "can substitute $\sin(\arcsin x)$ for $x$" the answers would be "no" and "only if the functions domain is initially restricted to a domain where $(\arcsin x)$ exists".  But that isn't what the question was.